# Is there an equivalent of `pcolormesh` (or `pcolor`) from `matplotlib.pyplot` in `plotly`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

As I am working on an interactive interface with `dash`, I am using `plotly` for my figures. However, I have limited experience with the package - I commonly use `matplotlib` to make figures.

Anyhow, I want to create a figure using 3D data, where the third dimension is expressed by means of colour. With `matplotlib`, I would use `pcolormesh` (or `pcolor`). Unfortunately, I cannot find an equivalent function within `plotly`. I cannot use `Contour` or alike, as the `z`-data should follow specific (`x`,`y`)-coordinates.

Let me clarify with an example. For convenience, we can use the following dummy data:

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 10))
y += 2 * np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi / 10)
z = np.exp(-x / 10)
```

What I want - and am able to produce using `matplotlib` - results from the following code (with the result after it):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

[image]

However, with `plotly`, I do not get any further than using a colour-coded `scatter`-plot:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, marker=dict(color=z))
)
```

This would look something like the following:
[image]

This is, however, not what I am aiming for. Enlarging the size of the `marker`s to 'trick' the viewer would not suffice, as the actual data is slightly more complex with varying gaps between the (`x`,`y`)-coordinates.

Hopefully, anyone can help me out. Thanks a lot for your effort!

**PS**. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918776/is-there-a-plotly-equivalent-to-matplotlib-pcolormesh) with a similar question. However, its solution does not apply to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase number of x-axis coordinates

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 200), np.linspace(0, 10))
y += 2 * np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi / 10)
z = np.exp(-x / 10)

go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x.flatten(), y=y.flatten(), mode="markers", marker_color=z.flatten()))
```

[image]

#### experimental

not fully working, inspired from [Matplotlib: save plot to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 10))
y += 2 * np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi / 10)
z = np.exp(-x / 10)

# plt.axes("off")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.axes.visible = False
ax = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
with io.BytesIO() as buff:
    fig.savefig(buff, format='raw', pad_inches=0, bbox_inches=0)
    buff.seek(0)
    data = np.frombuffer(buff.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
im = data.reshape((int(h), int(w), -1))

px.imshow(im)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the suggestions. The first method I have implemented right now, but I am not happy about it (makes the plotting very slow) and was mentioned as "not suitable". The latter is not fully working you say, which part is causing troubles?

Comment: it's the matplotlib axes being included in the image.  only invested some time in trying to get rid of them